# Excel - Row-wise to Column-wise Transform

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel for Mac (Office365), how can I best get row-wise formatted data of the form

```
| Year | Data |
---------------
| 2019 | 0.1  |
| 2019 | 0.3  |
| 2018 | 2.5  |
| 2017 | 0.9  |
| 2017 | 2.0  |
```

to a column-wise form like

```
| 2017 | 2018 | 2019 |
----------------------
| 0.9  | 2.5  | 0.1  |
| 2.0  |      | 0.3  |
```

?

The pivot table does not seem to be the right tool for this, as this would sum up my values. The Power Query tool is not currently available on Mac.

Answer (score 4):

Create Input/output table as per screenshot

In `D2`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$6/($A$2:$A$6=D$1),ROW(A1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can select the array and transpose it, but that will create duplicates for Years too.

Simply select the array go to the destination cell/area(where you want the new data to sit) and press (alt then E then S then V then E).
[image]